# Laravel multiple request order

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications

In my laravel application a user is currently logged in. I created the login via the auth scaffolding. He can press a button and a get request is performed in a new tab by my javascript code. The get request is creating a big pdf file that takes time to load. If the user is impatient he can just click at the old tab and press the button again even though the first get request is still running.

What will happen now?
There are two options:

1. The second get request will be executed after the first get request has been fully executed.
2. The second get request starts even though the first request has not finished yet.

I experimented a lot and experienced both cases. How does this work?

EDIT: Here is my code:

```
public function tmsheetsPanelPrintAll (Request $request)
    {
        ControllerFunctions::validate($request);
        

        //path vars
        $local_link_full = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . 'tmsheets\\tmpPrint\\';
        $local_link_short = 'tmsheets\\tmpPrint\\';
        $personalFolderName = FileHelper::emailToFilename(auth()->user()->email);

        //make directory
        Storage::disk('local')->makeDirectory($local_link_short . $personalFolderName);

        //helper
        $pdfHelper = new PdfHelper();
        $pdfMerger = PDFMerger::init();
        
        $filteredTmsheetIds = $request->session()->get('filteredTmsheetIds');

        //generate a new pdf in the corresponding folder foreach timesheet in session
        foreach ($filteredTmsheetIds as $index) {
            //generate PDF
            $pdf = $pdfHelper->generateTMsheetPDF($index);
            $filename = $pdfHelper->getTMsheetsFilename();
            Storage::disk('local')->put($local_link_short . $personalFolderName . '\\' . $filename , $pdf->output()); 
            $pdfMerger->addPDF($local_link_full . $personalFolderName . '\\' . $filename, 'all');
        }
        $pdfMerger->merge();
        Storage::disk('local')->deleteDirectory($local_link_short . $personalFolderName);
        $pdfMerger->save("file_name.pdf", "browser");
    }
```

I am using domPdf and pdfMerger. It works fine with the exception of clicking twice during a long calculation time. Note: There are several indexes in the session. If I run the code with only 7 PDF indexes to add together, everything works just fine, even if I click two times. Then the first request seems to finish, and everything is okay (see case 1 from above). If there are 122 indexes in the session, then case 2 happens. The code overlaps, the first request finishes but the second request returns the error: "file_get_contents -> failed to open stream: No such file or directory" . This error is thrown by lara-pdf-merger\src\LynX39\LaraPdfMerger\tcpdf\tcpdi.php:121 . I think it happens because the first request deletes the file at the end of the code and the second request still tries to access it.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I do not know why you let the user press again, I suggest you add loading placeholder to the page till the file loads (nicely if you notify the user with the loading progress) or easy way to disable the button till the first request success